# How to sort string correctly alphabetical order by special char İ, Ş, Ğ in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I write a select query that order by my data a column. This column type is varchar that contains string Ş - İ - Á - Í etc. is it posibble? it must be order İ after I , Ş after S, Á after A..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different collations have different sort orders, and different ways how they interpret umlauts.

for example: 
utf8_general_ci will sort Ö with O. If tried with the utf8_swedish_ci instead. That will have the correct sorting order, which (IIRC) is that ÄAÖ go to the end of the alphabet.

For background info, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collation-effect.html and [Mysql unicode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-sets.html)